# java date formarter not change the normal hour format to 24 hour format

Tags: java, oracle, date, timestamp

I have this javascript value JSON value  `21/09/2016 13:24:40` I want to receive that in my Java backend and transform it into a date and then into a timestamp.

I created this format:

```
SimpleDateFormat hourFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

And I used that format to convert the `String` into a `Date` like this:

```
initHour = hourFormat.parse((String) datosDTOParseados.get("initHour"));

Timestamp insertHour= new java.sql.Timestamp(initHour.getTime());
```

I print that value in the console and the hour is right, it's in the 24 hour format. But when I insert that into the Oracle database the hour is inserted in the normal format not in the 24 hour format.

I select the date in Oracle like this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(init_hour, 'dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss') From mytable where id='2';
```

I tried using this format changing the `HH` for a `hh` but the same thing happens:

```
SimpleDateFormat hourFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 24 hour Oracle format is `HH24`. Also minutes should be `MI`.

So your code should resemble:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(init_hour, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') From mytable where id='2';
```

Consult [Oracle Dates and Times](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-time.html).

Comment: Upvoted, but the stuff about inserting is probably needless since it looks as though he is inserting via JDBC using a `java.sql.Timestamp`, so `to_date` wouldn't be necessary.